# Unable to understand Python Requests Response

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am making a script that interacts with a web page. Unfortunately I am unable to understand the response. Also the response should be in a JSON format as the response when I use inspect element is `{"data":{"requestOrder":true}}`

I send the post using the following

```
enter = s.post(postlink, headers = postheaders, json=jsondata)
print enter.text
```

This then prints the following response

```
ƒHΒµ¥:.ƒ¶•b±=Β/<¨Β>>ΣΙ�Λ—„-�ΎΔ8ΐ NVφ¨�αe!ΦOΗ§M¬-¬6Ζυy΅m›!ψƒΘ�2ΎΆ©ό)ούΠ3ηθΚ|ΆαΎDΨ®��ΨQ®$”XCηsf�ΔΛk
```

I am also getting the following sometimes:

```
ŉF�ᶐc♹v5
```

This is a frustrating issue.

I look forward to hearing from you!

Thanks again.

Comment: Is the file you are accessing definitely JSON? Can you open the value of `postlink` in a browser to check?

Comment: I have used inspect element on Google chrome to see a response and it looks like this {"data":{"requestOrder":true}}. When using requests I am sending the exact same post request but the get the response displayed above.

Comment: Can you share the URL?